# Tehillim while waiting for medical test results for an unborn baby

Tags: names, pregnancy-birth, tehilim-psalms, baby-infant

[The suggestion is made](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29640/170) that one recite tehillim #119 "with the letters corresponding to the name and mothers name" of someone awaiting medical test results. What if the sick person is an unborn baby (who of course has no name yet)? Also, it is necessary to pray for the mother?

Comment: Anonymous, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! If it's personally relevant to you, I wish you a healthy birth at the right time. After you check out the answers that have already been offered for your question, I hope you'll look around the site and find other great material, perhaps including our 64 other questions about [tag:pregnancy-birth].

Comment: It is entirely appropriate to pray for the mother, as any outcome regarding the fetus affects her. May G-d give you strength through your ordeal.

Comment: @msh dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/how-do-you-pray-for-a-sick-baby-who-has-not-yet-been-named

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe, except of course for the "Also, it is necessary to pray for the mother?" question. Otoh conceivably how to pray for an unborn vs. a born baby may differ. I'll vote keep open.